# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL - in the same domain

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm trying to access to the URL of the parent window from an iFrame but I got an error on my server:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://www.domain.com/folder/ from frame with URL
>   http://www.domain.com/folder/file.html. The frame being accessed set
>   'document.domain' to 'domain.com', but the frame requesting access did
>   not. Both must set 'document.domain' to the same value to allow
>   access.

I'm in the same domain so I don't understand why I get this error.
For your information everything works good in localhost.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found the solution.
I put this code and that works:

```
document.domain = 'domain.com';
```

Comment: Where did you add that code?  To the first URL (http://www.domain.com/folder/) or the second ( http://www.domain.com/folder/file.html)?