# Blocked iframe in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

Using iframe I'm getting the following error

Blocked a frame with origin "http://002.www2.domain.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://test.com:5050". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "domain.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.

I already read about javascript cross domain policy, but the thing is that with other browsers this codes are working

```
<html>
<head>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">       
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">            
            function hide_wait() {
                <? if ($gs_frame) { ?>                   
                    parent.document.getElementById('container_set').rows = '78,0,*';
                <? } else { ?>
                    location.href='<?= $url ?>';
                <? } ?>    
            }

        </script>

</head>

<frameset rows="78,*,0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" id="container_set">        
    <frame src="<?= $gs_frame ?>" id="container_1" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" style="height: 78px; overflow: hidden; border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E2E2">
    <frame src="loading.php?hr=<?= $hr ?>" id="wait" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="height: 100px;">
    <frame src="<?= $url ?>" id="container_2" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload="hide_wait();"> 
</frameset>    
<body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid I do not have the reputation of marking it as a possible duplicate. Hence my only option is to paste the link here. Hope it helps.

[Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL - in the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592685/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url-in-the-same-domain)